# How do we represent relations in a free group by loops in a manifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Hypothesis:** Let $F$ be a finitely presented group s.t.

$$
F = \left\langle S \mid R \right\rangle
$$

Let $X$ be a $4$-manifold.

**Question:** I've seen it asserted that we can represent each relation in $R$ by a loop in $X$.  But in what sense can we represent relations in $R$ by loops in $X$?  What precisely does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

See the same question here with a nice answer :

### Heading ##https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15411/finite-generated-group-realized-as-fundamental-group-of-manifolds

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I made a post asking questions about the outline more or less presented in that MathOverflow link.  It might be of interest to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788097/showing-that-every-finitely-presented-group-has-a-4-manifold-with-it-as-its-fu